# NLog not finding any extension assembly without project reference

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to use a custom NLog target with a third party application (UiPath) that uses NLog for logging purposes. As I cannot add my target assembly as a dependency here, I copied my assembly dll into the same folder where UiPath stores NLog.dll and NLog.config.

I have updated NLog.config as per the docs at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component and expected the custom target to be registered from the assembly dll.

Now the config looks like this (MyTarget is a minimal target that replaces the actual target, so that I could rule out dependency or runtime issues from the target itself):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  internalLogFile="D:\nlog-internal.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
  <variable name="WorkflowLoggingDirectory" value="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/UiPath/Logs" />
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="WorkflowLogFiles" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" writeTo="MyFirst" final="true" />
  </rules>
  <targets>
    <target type="File" name="WorkflowLogFiles" fileName="${WorkflowLoggingDirectory}/${shortdate}_Execution.log" layout="${basedir} ==> ${message}," keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true" encoding="utf-8" writeBom="true" />
    <target type="MyFirst, MyTarget" name="MyFirst" Host="na" layout="${message}" />
  </targets>
</nlog>
```

Note that this example should register the assembly from the <target> tag using its FQN. I have also tried with:

```xml
<extensions>
    <assembly>MyTarget</assembly>
</extensions>
```

and:

```xml
<target type="MyFirst" name="MyFirst" layout="${message}" />
```

Which yields the same result in nlog-internal.txt:

```
Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error loading extensions: MyTarget
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyTarget, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyTarget, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I am at a loss as to why it can't load the assembly like this. Probably overlooking something very basic.

Created a minimal reproduction: (Program.cs below)

```cs
using NLog;

namespace Example
{
    static class Program
    {
        static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void Main()
        {

            Logger.Info("Hello!");
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
            
    }
}
```

Which behaves identically when trying to configure the extension and target from NLog.config. If I add the MyTarget.dll as a dependency to this project before compilation, the target is found and behaves as expected.

*edit: changed assembly to dependency in last sentence (see comment below)*

Comment: NLog-project contains unit-test that verifies that `type="MyFirst, MyTarget"` works when `MyTarget`-assembly contains a target-class with attribute `[Target("MyFirst")]`. Ofcourse it only works when the application-project references the assembly `MyTarget` as it must be found in the bin-folder. You are wellcome to [create an issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues) for the NLog-project, and attach a minimal-example-project that fails.

Comment: I think I misformulated in the last sentence. Will update. The issue I encounter is that the target is not found when the assembly is in the bin folder of a compiled project that uses NLog, but is found when the assembly is added as a dependency in VS before building the solution. The question is how to use a custom target on an application using NLog that one gets as a binary and not source?

Comment: Usually you publish your extension as nuget-package, and then reference the nuget-package in the projects where needed.

Comment: Yes, I tried using a published package from NuGet, too. Installed with PS's Install-Package, but yields the same result in this use-case (not a VS project, but a third party application that configures the logs I want to capture)

Comment: There are many available NLog extension-nuget-packages. Maybe test that you are able to to use one of the existing nuget-packages. Guessing that your own nuget-package might be missing something, or something is failing when adding NLog-extension as nuget-package. Best of luck

Comment: I have tried several, see answer above. The outcome is consistently that the extension cannot be loaded. It only seems to find it when used as a project dependency in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that loading an assembly by name from the config file does not work as expected. Even when the dll is in the same folder.

*Not working* when you want to use a target from a dll in the same folder as NLog.dll and NLog.config:

```xml
<extensions> 
  <add assembly="MyTarget"/> 
</extensions>
```

Also *not working*:

```xml
<targets> 
  <target name="mytarget" type="CustomTarget, MyAssemblyName" />
</targets>
```

What *does* work, is using the (rather undocumented) `assemblyFile` attribute:

```xml
<extensions> 
  <add assemblyFile="MyTarget.dll"/> 
</extensions>
```